# How should I install a python module when I don't know the installation command

Tags: python, pip, installation

For example:

When I want to use OpenSSL, in python I use `from OpenSSL import SSL` and to install OpenSSL I do `apt-get install python-openssl` or `pip install pyopenssl`.

---

EDIT: Thank you very much for everybody that answered it. But what if I don't know how to install 12345.

Let's say there is a library called 12345 that I don't know how to install and I want to use its module ABCDE. Then in a Python script I would write `from 12345 import ABCDE` and to install the library I would try `apt-get install python-12345` or `pip install 12345`. But not always this works. In this case how can I use that module?

Is there a command line to "install" directly the module or any way that I can discover its related library?

For example:
If I try `import 12345` I get the error:

`>>> import 12345
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    import 12345
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

I think the question become a bit confused. I'm editing it to try to make it better to understand.

Comment: Installing 12345 also installs ABCDE. No further installation is needed. You would install 12345 using one of the examples that you've already provided and import it in your script by using the from 12345 import ABCDE command.

Answer (score 0):

You can see this information using the built in `help` function.

For example, I have `tornado` installed.

```
> import tornado
> help(tornado)
```

The start of the output from this command is currently as following;

> Help on package tornado:
>
> NAME
>
> **tornado** - The Tornado web server and tools

If the package has been correctly configured, the name of the package is listed before hyphen in the NAME section. I've bolded it for you.

In this case then, the pip command to install the tornado package is simply

```
pip install tornado
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. I edited it since the question was a bit confused and added more informations...

Comment: I thought `12345` was just an example... That's not a valid module name. Try s12345 or something else that resolves to a valid variable name.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use ABCDE from module 12345, then all you need to install is  module 12345 (you can't install just 'ABCDE').  So in general, the answer to you question is :

```
pip install 12345
```

Many modules come as "batteries included", so you don't necessarily need to install something.
For example, if you do:

```
>>> import random
>>>
```

You don't get any error, so that module is part of the Python Standard Library and don't need installing.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I edited it since the question was a bit confused and added more informations...

Answer (score 0):

You can't just get the modules you need, you have to install the library that contains it. Find needed library in [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi)

```
from library import module
```

This command will be the way you want. If you get on error, do this.

```
import library
```

This command import all of modules in library.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I edited it since the question was a bit confused and added more informations...